# Numpy array striping strings via broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have the following code

```
import numpy
s = numpy.array([['210123278414410005', '101232784144610006']], dtype='object')
print(s, type(s), s.shape)
s[0][0] = s[0][0][13:]
s[0][1] = s[0][1][13:]    
print(s, type(s), s.shape)
```

---

This gives me the desired output:

```
[['210123278414410005' '101232784144610006']] 
[['10005' '10006']]
```

As you may see 13 characters on the left are gone.
Is it possible to broadcast this operation?

I tried,

```
s[0][:] = [[s[0][0]]][0][0][13:]
```

---

But this doesn't give the correct output like before.

```
[['10005' '10005']]
```

Comment: Maybe some of https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html may help but I had no luck in 30 min of trying...

Comment: Use `[i,j,..,]` when indexing numpy, not [][][]..,

Comment: Look at the np.char set of string functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [22]: s = np.array([['210123278414410005', '101232784144610006']], dtype='object')                                                                  
In [23]: s                                                                      
Out[23]: array([['210123278414410005', '101232784144610006']], dtype=object)
In [24]: s.shape                                                                
Out[24]: (1, 2)
```

Since this is an object dtype array, a good starting point is `frompyfunc` which also returns an object dtype array:

```
In [25]: np.frompyfunc(lambda s: s[13:],1,1)(s)                                 
Out[25]: array([['10005', '10006']], dtype=object)
```

`s[0,0]` is a Python string.  `s[0,0][13:]` is a string operation.

In general operations on object dtype arrays require a near-python level iteration, even math.  There aren't any builtin `numpy` operations to take substrings.  `np.char` has a bunch of functions that apply string methods to elements of a string dtype array.  But they aren't particularly fast, and they don't include this substring task.

Or for the last 5:

```
In [33]: np.frompyfunc(lambda s: s[-5:],1,1)(s)                                 
Out[33]: array([['10005', '10006']], dtype=object)
```

Comparing this to Colin's answer:

```
In [37]: sbig = np.resize(s, (1000,1000))                                       
In [38]: timeit np.mod(sbig.astype('uint64'),100000).astype('U')                
754 ms ± 9.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [39]: timeit np.frompyfunc(lambda s: s[-5:],1,1)(sbig)                       
245 ms ± 428 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Looking further, it appears that the `astype('U')` step is the big time consumer, converting numbers to strings.

Comment: Excellent, there are only about ~400 questions so far on numpy broadcasting. Your first tip was to look into [`np.char`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html) set of functions. Are you saying these are not fast enough, even though they are vectorized?

Comment: Also, is it possible for `np.frompyfunc` to do things inplace. Currently, it returns the result?

Comment: With your `object` dtype, `frompyfunc` passes a string to your function.  A string cannot be modified in-place.  So your function can only return a new string.  To do in-place changes you'd have to iterate and set `s[i,j] = s[i,j][-5:]`.  Most `numpy` operations create a new array, even if it is a temporary buffer.  True in-place ones are rare.

Answer (score 1):

Use comprehension

```
import numpy
s = numpy.array([['210123278414410005', '101232784144610006']], dtype='object')
s = np.asarray([[i[13:] for e in s for i in e]])
print(s, type(s), s.shape)
```

Result:

```
[['10005' '10006']] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (1, 2)
```

Comment: I am not sure this is broadcasting since it uses for loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your array items to numbers, trim them, and then convert back to strings:

```
WIDTH = 5
MOD = 10 ** WIDTH
numpy.char.zfill((s.astype(numpy.int64) % MOD).astype('str'), WIDTH)
#array([['10005', '10006']], dtype='<U5')
```

Comment: I may have zeros anywhere.

Comment: Got `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`

Comment: I used the numbers from your example. Are your numbers bigger? I changed the datatype explicitly to `numpy.int64`.

Comment: You may provide the full example, I will copy/paste test it.

Comment: My guess is that `rjust` has a potential, but again I could not make it work in 30min. These are vectorized instructions...

Answer (score 1):

A clumsy approach would be to convert your 'number string' to an integer, perform a modulo to the desired length then convert back to a string:

```
s = numpy.mod(s[0,].astype(numpy.uint64),100000).astype('U')
```

Which gives the desired result.

Comment: It works, however, I hope there is even better approach.

Comment: Are the strings always 18 characters long?  And if not, is it more important to strip the first 13 chars or retain the last 5?

Comment: It is more important to retain the last 5. Strings may vary in size. They are 18 chars at this moment, but may ...

Comment: If this is so, then my solution should hold.  Unfortunately AFAIK, numpy doesn't handle string slicing.  So  this would be the best purely numpy solution I can see.

Comment: the other answer I found really levels up. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: hopefully he will be as kind to return the favor ;)